# Reading in .dat files with the word "upper" included causes problems

Tags: python, pandas, file

This is the code I use to read in .dat files:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep='\s+')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(df['yh_center[2]'], df['tot_scale01[4]'], 'ro')
plt.xlabel('yh_center')
plt.ylabel('tot_scale01[4]')
plt.savefig('name.pdf')
plt.show()
```

It reads in correctly when there is no lonely word "upper" in the dat. file.
However I will have many .dat files that have the word "upper" involved that cause errors.

The .dat file looks like:

```
#labels: yh_lower[1]   yh_center[2]   yh_upper[3]   tot_scale01[4]
#neval: 200000
#overflow:lower center upper    0.0000000000E+000    0.0000000000E+000    0.0000000000E+000    0.0000000000E+000
```

then on line 4 the actual data comes in

```
-4.4000000000E+000   -4.3000000000E+000   -4.2000000000E+000    0.0000000000E+000
```

Then i have 43 lines more of the data and the final line is

```
#nx: 3
```

(where actually there are over 100 columns of data, but that should change...the principle should be shown with the first 4 columns)

The full error report is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-00512d6cb966>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('Private, so deleted that one here')

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/ttp/manbrunn/Documents/NNLOJETexe/HJtest/funktioniert.py", line 15, in <module>
    plt.plot(df['yh_center[2]'], df['tot_scale01[4]'], 'ro')

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3099, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1374, in plot
    self.add_line(line)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1504, in add_line
    self._update_line_limits(line)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1515, in _update_line_limits
    path = line.get_path()

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 874, in get_path
    self.recache()

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 575, in recache
    x = np.asarray(xconv, np.float_)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 462, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'upper'
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include some text examples of your CSV file that are failing.

Comment: I found out that the problem was not the hashtag. It worked also with the hashtags. But when I do not remove the word "upper" it doesn't work with the error above.

Comment: I can't duplicate with the small amount of "data" you gave. Reading a single line containing the line you gave does not cause an error. In general, Pandas is usually smart enough to read the data as 'object' in case there are strings.

Comment: In any case, you can try adding the argument `dtype='object'` to the `read_csv` function. Then you'll have to replace all words in your dataframe with nulls or numbers, after which you can convert to float.

Comment: I guess it is a joke. This was just because I didn't put it into the code brackets. Now I did.

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-parse the data by removing any leading text from each line before passing it to pandas, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

with open('data.dat') as f_input:
    header = next(f_input).split()[1:]
    next(f_input)
    next(f_input)

    data = [line.strip().split() for line in f_input]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[:-1], dtype='float', columns=header)
```

This version is able to also extract the column names from the first row.

---

If the `upper` only appears on the third line (and not randomly throughout the file), you could simply use `skiprows` to tell Pandas to start reading from the forth line onwards, and as you have a `#nx: 3` in the final line, use `skipfooter` to skip that too:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep='\s+', skiprows=3, skipfooter=1, header=None)
```

Tested on Pandas 0.22.0

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Now there is a new error
   KeyError: 'yh_center[2]'
I guess because everything now is a float and i can't refer to yh_center anymore.

Comment: Try adding `next(f_input)` twice before the `data =` line to skip over the first two rows.

Comment: The error stays. So I guess I was wrong with my idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Also try the `skiprows` and `skipfooter` idea I've added. You could also put your `.dat` file on something like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and add a link to it here, we could then recreate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Unfortunately the error stays the same. That is very weird.

Comment: As I said, if you upload your file to pastebin, I would be able to recreate and diagnose the problem.

Comment: Not sure if it worked, but here should be the link: https://pastebin.com/nXdbifqZ

Comment: Both versions should now work. I would suggest the `pd.read_csv()` approach is better though.

Comment: For the second one the error stays.
For the first one it now seems to work.

Maybe I get your advice wrong for the second one. 
Should I have there while loop too? Just to know. The error stays with and without the loop.

What did you do that the first version now works? I mean what does your code do there?

Comment: I think I removed the space from the `split()` command. They both work fine on my Python 3.6 / Pandas 0.22.0, perhaps you could try updating?  No loop is required in the second one.